# PHP Conditional setting to Boolean True or False

Tags: php, html, boolean

I set the following PHP Code:

```
if($motherFirst == 'yes')
{$motherBool = true;}
else
{$motherBool = false;}

if($fatherFirst == 'no')
{$fatherBool = true;}
else
{$fatherBool = false;}
```

I have checked that I'm obtaining Yes or No as a value for both $motherFirst and $fatherFirst by doing an echo.

I am then using $motherBool and $fatherBool to post boolean (true or false) not as string in an API call.

However it appears that they are being assigned true or false of type string. What can I do to convert them to Boolean?

Above has been corrected, but now have issue with following:

I'm also sending the json as follows:

```
 $data_string = '{
    "motherData": false,
    "fatherData": true
  }';
```

Which works, but when I put as follows, it doesn't work:

```
 $data_string = '{
    "motherData": '.$motherBool.',
    "fatherData": '.$fatherBool.'
  }';
```

Can you let me know?

Comment: Use `=` not `==`. You're comparing instead of assigning. You can delete this question.

Comment: Also, `$motherBool = ($motherFirst == 'yes')` will do the job. No need for the `if` statement.

Comment: Rigth - how stupid of me!

Comment: I have an additional, can you help me on this if I'm missing something please :) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered but here is a simplification.

```
$motherBool = ($motherFirst == 'yes');
$fatherBool = ($fatherFirst == 'no');
```

In your second question you're echoing a bool as if its a string which will print 0 or 1, not true/false as your expecting. You need to convert the bool to a string. for example,

```
 $data_string = '{
    "motherData": '.($motherBool ? 'true' : 'false').',
    "fatherData": '.($fatherBool ? 'true' : 'false').'
  }';
```